# Defining counts of unique configurations for items in the same column

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

Good Afternoon All. I have a report in which I'm trying to define unique product configurations for our products based upon a common "PhantomParent".  Below I've included a table of how our data is formatted and what I'm attempting to have the report show.

[Database Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTvDl.jpg)

In the attached table's image I want to define the Stock Code Configurations for each X0908P part # (in the attached example the only difference is the spring used, 8017 vs 8019).

I also have other X0908P configurations that are not shown here.  At the end of the day I would like a report that is formatted like the following (I've included additional examples of configurations in the results below):

[Report output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNjxf.jpg)

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: Honestly, unable to understand what is your exact issue

Comment: Looking for crystal reports to export a report that looks like the second picture from the first dataset.  In the dataset example there are 2 Jobs with two different configurations for the X0908P phantom part.  In our database there are thousands of jobs and I want to determine their configuration.

Comment: So thats fine but what is the logic you are combining 7 components as a set? Is it a random one or there is some logic behind the combinations

Comment: The product we manufacture uses a system similar to dell, we have a standard part that can also be upgraded.  We're trying to determine which upgrade combinations are most popular so we can provide that information to our distributors (allowing them to stock the best selling custom configurations).  In my report output example the common configuration has 10 and the best selling upgrade (w/ 8019 spring) has 5.